# Recreate Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, 3d, arc

How can I recreate this figure?

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-12cm]
\draw[rounded corners=35pt](0,0)--(8,0);
\draw[rounded corners=35pt](0,-2)--(8,-2);
\draw (8.5,-1) arc (0:360:0.5cm and 1cm);
\draw (0.5,-1) arc (0:360:0.5cm and 1cm);
\node (a) at (0,0.5) {};
\node (b) at (4,-2.5) {$t$};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}
\draw [black, dashed] circle [radius=3] (0,0);
\draw [black, dashed] circle [radius=4.3];
\end{scope}
%\draw[arrows = {-Latex[width'=0pt .5, length=10pt]}]  (-5.5,3) -- (-3.5,3);
 \draw[arrows = {-Latex[width'=0pt .5, length=5pt]}]  (-5.5,3) to[out=30,in=150]  node[midway,above] {}  (-3.5,3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Source:DiFrancesco,Conformal Field Theory, Figure 6.1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{
    node1/.style = {inner sep=0},
    arrow/.style = {-latex},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    %cylinder
    \node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=2,
    minimum height=3cm,minimum width=1.5cm,
    shape border rotate=180] (A) {};
    
    %dashed lines
    \node[node1] (D1) at (-20pt,-22pt) {};
    \node[node1] (D2) at (-20pt,22pt) {};
    \draw[dashed] (D1) to[out=60,in=-60] (D2) node[midway,xshift=-5pt] {$\scriptscriptstyle t1$};;
    
    \node[node1] (D3) at (10pt,-22pt) {};
    \node[node1] (D4) at (10pt,22pt) {};
    \draw[dashed] (D3) to[out=60,in=-60] (D4) node[midway,xshift=25pt] {$\scriptscriptstyle t2$};
    
    %arrows
    \draw[arrow] (-40pt,-16pt) to[out=75,in=-75] (-40pt,16pt) node[midway,xshift=-42pt] {$\scriptscriptstyle x$};   
    \draw[arrow] (-0.5,-1) -- (0.5,-1) node[midway,below] {$\scriptscriptstyle t$};
    
    \draw[arrow] (2,0) -- (3,0);
    
    %circle
    
    \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt] (t1) at (5,0) {};
    
    \node[draw,circle,dashed,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=35pt,label=right:{$\scriptscriptstyle t1$}] (t1) at (5,0) {};
    \node[draw,circle,dashed,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=70pt,label=right:{$\scriptscriptstyle t2$}] (t2) at (5,0) {};
    
    \draw[arrow] (6.5,0.5) arc (15:70:1.5) node[midway,above] {$\scriptscriptstyle x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]